# How to reload my app after deleting a data, without loosing the selected options through drop downs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a School App with AngularJS where I have a Delete option for classes on a selected course/batch. Whenever I delete a class in a course/batch, the class gets deleted & the app reloads but loosing to stay on the same selected course/batch showing the rest of the classes, instead clearing the selected course/batch AS WELL from the drop down list.
I've researched through many forums and tried to get a solution for this as now I seek help from an expert than me.
My $state, after deleting a class is defined properly in the controller.The URL in class.config(course/class) is retrieving after deleting a class but not staying on the selected course/batch. Below I've given my controller & config file along with a screenshot of my page.

class.detail.controller.js File

```
//Delete Class
    vm.deleteClass = function (cclass) {
        var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('Would you like to Delete ' + cclass.Name + '?')
        .ariaLabel('Class delete Confirmation')
        .cancel('Cancel')
        .ok('Delete');
          $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
            //_event.loading = true;
            cclass.$delete({ cclassId: cclass.Id }).then(function (data) {
                notify.success('Class deleted');
                 $state.go('triangular-no-scroll.class-management.class',{},  
{reload:true});                   
            }, function () {
                notify.error('Class deleting failed');
            }).finally(function () {
                _event.loading = false;
            });
        });
    };
```

class.config.js File

```
.state('triangular-no-scroll.class-management.class', {
            url: '/course/class',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/course/class/class.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'ClassController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                courses: function ($stateParams, CourseService) {
                    var data = CourseService.getCourseList();
                    return data;
                }
            }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwjcV.jpg)

Comment: set your model data in localStorage, hopefully you will be using redux and you only need to place your data in the state tree and let it flow if not, then hopefully you'll have the data in a service and  your controller can read it from there, if not then hopefully you can read the data localstorage from your routes  resolve clause and inject it into your controller.

Comment: Thanks @dayan as you've suggested, localstorage does the trick however I've found rather simple way to get this done as given in my answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without setting the app to refresh after deleting a class as in my case above, set an announcement in Angular using $rootScope.$broadcast in to the function and pass in the data that required to be actioned(In my case 'classes').

class.detail.controller.js File

```
//Delete Class
    vm.deleteClass = function (cclass) {
        var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('Would you like to Delete ' + cclass.Name + '?')
        .ariaLabel('Class delete Confirmation')
        .cancel('Cancel')
        .ok('Delete');
          $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
            //_event.loading = true;
            cclass.$delete({ cclassId: cclass.Id }).then(function (data) {
                notify.success('Class deleted');
                $rootScope.$broadcast('courseClass:deleted', cclass);
                 $state.go('triangular-no-scroll.class-management.class',{},  
{reload:false});                   
            }, function () {
                notify.error('Class deleting failed');
            }).finally(function () {
                _event.loading = false;
            });
        });
    };
```

When the program hits this code, the message that is set within will be announced and related controllers can catch it by using Angular $scope.$on.

class.controller.js

```
 $scope.$on('courseClass:deleted', function (event, data) {
        if (data != null)
            loadClassesByBatchId(data.BatchId);
    });
```

Then of course we can code what we want to display(In my case load the remaining classes by selected Batch ID after deleting a class).